# Each ListView item opens layout with different text

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

How my onClickListener should look like if I need to open layout with different text for each ListView item and I have a lot of ListView items (about 50)? Do I need to create new activity or layout file for each new item? Is it possible to use one activity for all items?
This is my **MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // ListView
    private ListView listView;

    // Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    String items [];

    // ArrayList
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //ListView data in res/values/arrays.xml
        items =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.listItem, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                /* 
                I know that I can put here I can put something like this:

                case 0 :Intent appInfo = new Intent(About.this, Activity1.class);
                    startActivity(appInfo);
                    break;
                case 1 :Intent appInfo = new Intent(About.this, Activity2.class);
                    startActivity(appInfo);
                    break;
                case 2 :Intent appInfo = new Intent(About.this, Activity3.class);
                    startActivity(appInfo);
                    break;

                    BUT DO I NEED REPEAT THIS MORE THAN 20 TIMES?!
                    */

                }
        });
    }
}
```

Some  system apps like Settings has a lot of ListView and layouts and I don't believe that it has new activity for each layout.

Comment: Show what you have tried, please do not expect people to simply write things for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new single activity and pass the text to that activity.

Something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(About.this, <NEW_ACTIVITY>.class);
intent.putExtra("text_key", items[position]);
startActivity(intent);
```

on the other activity, retrieve the text like this (can be on the onCreate method):

```
String text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("text_key");
```

Comment: Where I need to write my text? (sorry for noon question)

Comment: Sorry, never mind. At first I don't understand, but now everything is clear. Thanks.